# I want to connect a button from my UI to my python code.

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, designer

Im first trying to connect a sample cancel button that when clicked will show 'Hello'. Again, thats just a sample. I just like to know how can I connect my ui to the python code that id like to use for the cancel button. I hope someone can help me. Im new to python.

Heres the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

from A3AMainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

self.connect(self.btn_inv_cancel.clicked.connect(self.on_click))

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        QMessageBox.Information(Self, "hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Remove the `@pyqtSlot()` line and fix the indentantion of the line above it.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot

from A3AMainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Announcement.","Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow() 
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A3AMainWindow.py

```
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(134, 110, 121, 71))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I patterned your codes to mine. Thank you! This really helps! Just a question, do i have to put @pyqtSlot() all the time for every function of button?

Comment: ...Connecting a signal to a decorated Python method also has the advantage of reducing the amount of memory used and is slightly faster....